Error 400: invalid_request with redirect_URI with Oauth2.0 and expo go
Im trying to add google sign in to my react native expo app, but when i click to the button i encounter this error in expo go:
Access blocked: authorisation error
hernanz.reio@gmail.com
You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.
You can let the app developer know that this app doesn't comply with one or more Google validation rules.
Learn more about this error
If you are a developer of Wisdom, see error details
•
Error 400: invalid_request
Error 400: invalid _request
Detalles de la solicitud:
redirect_uri=exp://192.168.0.30:8081
flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow
const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState();
    const [user, setUser] = useState();

    const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useIdTokenAuthRequest({
        
        iosClientId: 'XXX',
        androidClientId: 'XXX',
        expoClientId: 'XXX', 
        
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (response?.type === 'success') {
            setAccessToken(response.authentication.accessToken);
            accessToken && fetchUserInfo();
            console.log(accessToken)
    }
    }, [response, accessToken]);

    const getUserData = async () => {
        let userInfoResponse = await fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me', {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` }            
        })
        userInfoResponse.json().then(data => {setUser(data)})
    }

I dont undertand the error. For some reason, when i add online clientId and a redirect uri it works until shows a screen with "Something went wrong trying to finish signing in. Please close this screen to go back to the app.". Also when i add a redirect uri to the code above it shows an error saying redirect_uri_mismatch, but i dont understand because i dont have any redirect uri in the ios client id. please help
I expect to work google sing in and solve the invalid_request_error and redirect_uri_mismatch errors
